# "Why" in Beijing Dialect

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

I've been wondering how to correctly say "why" in Beijing dialect.

I know that in colloquial beijing mandarin 什么 is pronounced as shém with a final m. I thus thought the same was for 为什么 as weishem.

However, I came across this website ( https://pinyin.sogou.com/zimeiti/article/1255 ) where it says it is pronounced "味日末", wei ri mo. If it is "味日末", does this refer to wei [ʐ] mo or wei [ɻ] mo?

However, wiktionary says that 吗儿 is the Beijing synonym for 什么 (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%97%8E%E5%85%92#Chinese). Should it be 为吗儿?

Which is correct?

Comment: 为儿什么 could be something like wei re me, 么 is also easy to morph me —> mo and vice versa.

Comment: I know you're struggling to find good resources, but be very careful about anything where Chinese characters are used to show pronunciation. It will be a very rough approximation and it will be impossible to know what sound the writer intended.

Comment: (Disclaimer: beginner). /ʐ/ seems more logical because sh is /ʂ/. Voicing happens between syllables => /ʂ/ becomes /ʐ/. 
And the Wiktionary entry says 吗儿 is a synonym, but 什么 is still listed first - that means it's a valid synonym (and probably more common). And I don't think we can go and replace every 什么 with 吗儿, as it will depends on the context where it is used - which words surround it, which situation the speaker is in, the speaker's class / educational background / etc.